# why "android:actionBarStyle" is used for level>11?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have trace Holo.Theme.Light.DarkActionBar with value-11, and see this:

```
<style name="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar" parent="Sherlock.__Theme.DarkActionBar">
       ...
       <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse</item>
       ...
</style>
```

And Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, is an ancestor of Holo.Theme.Light.DarkActionBar.
So, if I want to derive a new theme, why I have to cover "android:actionBarStyle" for level>=11 ?

Could anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActionBarSherlock uses its own implementation to draw the ActionBar on pre level 11 devices. For this case the styles that apply to ActionBarSherlock are used. On devices with level 11 or higher, the native ActionBar is used and so only the styles for this component are used. On Android 3 or 4, the app just behaves like ActionBarSherlock would not be used in your project.